# CRM 2011 - How to retrieve Global option set using SOAP request in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have the global option set created in CRM 2011 with the name "my_global_option_set". I would like to retrieve this along with the values using JavaScript. I prefer making the SOAP request and I do not have the GUID of the created global option set.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft recently released a [SOAP Javascript library](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2014/04/28/new-microsoft-crm-sdk-sample-sdk-soap-js.aspx).  It's for 2013, but besides the Action Message stuff, it should all be the same.  I'd look there.